# Java Spark Framework, deploy failing

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, spark-framework

This seems like it should be a trivial task. But I can't quite figure out what I am suppose to do. I am new to Maven/Spark. And after searching around, looking thorough the docs and what not. I can't figure out how to start my spark application?

I followed this guide to get set up in Intellij. 
https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/04/02/setting-up-a-spark-project-with-maven.html

I can run all of the maven tasks, except deploy.

[image]

**Deploy fails with this error.**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project framework: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I am not sure if that matters or not? Is deploy the task intended to start the server? I am not sure.

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.krishollenbeck.framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is what the DOCS say.

> What about starting the server? The server is automatically started
>   when you do something that requires the server to be started (i.e.
>   declaring a route or setting the port). You can also manually start
>   the server by calling init().

http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#stopping-the-server

Okay? What does that mean? Normally there is some command or something to start a server.

**Question: TL;DR**

How do I start the spark server?

**Additional sort of off topic:**

Is spark still maintained? Is this a bad framework to use? I am looking for a light weight java server. Most of the app logic will be handled client side. Just need to handle some basic login/ CRUD stuff on the server side. And constructing some restful API.

**Project Structure: (FYI)**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**RUN your main class from Intellij. OR, if you want to run it with maven do this:**

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=my.IakaMain
```

and make sure you change my.IakaMain with yourpackage.YourClassName

**Or run via Intellij Debug Configuration: (like so)**

[image]

Run and view: (please note the port number is not the usual 80 or 8080)

http://localhost:4567/hello

**Note: If you get this warning (annoying).**

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
>   See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details.

Add this to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe it is the reason for my error. I was actually running into an issue with intellij. It kept trying to compile using 1.5. Even after I had changed everything to 1.8.

Comment: Still get the same error using `<build>` trying to run deploy

Comment: Because the deploy phase needs a distribution management section in your pom as stated in the doc of the deploy maven plugin

Comment: This got me going in the right direction. I got it running. I edited your answer with some extra info / steps. Hope you don't mind. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

To start the server the doc also mentions:

> You can also manually start the server by calling init().
>   See: http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#stopping-the-server

Last commit being 4 days ago, I'd bet it is still supported.

See https://github.com/perwendel/spark/

Finally your issue comes from the fact that you need to tell the maven deploy plugin where to deploy exactly with a  tag:

> To enable this mojo to function, you must include a valid  section POM

See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html

As for a lightweight database, I use [hsqldb](http://hsqldb.org) but then I guess that's more of a matter of taste.

Comment: `You can also manually start the server by calling init()` I read that too. Posted it in my question. But I am a bit confused  by that? Was looking for an example.

Comment: Launch your app and then check on localhost:4567 as stated by @moldovean

Comment: I got it running now.  Thanks for the the help.